# Cant positioning Backgroud image behind another component in react

Tags: css, reactjs

i have two components in react (green(nav) and red border(banner)). Actually i setted the background image of the red bordered component, with following css:

```
.banner {
    margin-top: 0;
    background-image: url("../../assets/img/banner/banner- 
    bg.png");
    padding: 260px 0 100px 0;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: red 2px solid;
}
```

Image of actual state:
[image]

I want it like this:
[image]

Comment: you want both of the banners have 1bg ? Combined Bg?

Comment: the background from the bottom component should overflow to max top without hiding the top component.

Comment: You can not have a background go outside of the element's actual dimensions. Either apply the background to the common parent element both of these components have (and leave their respective backgrounds transparent), or make the banner cover the whole screen, and then position your navigation absolute or fixed on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

you can put both banners inside a container & place bg-image on that

```css
.banner {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 260px 0 100px 0;
  border: red 2px solid;
}

.nav {
  padding: 20px 0 100px 0;
  border: green 2px solid;
}

.bannerBg {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1664142315016-89b004b66788?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80");
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section class="bannerBg">
  <div class="nav banner">
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

I Fixed the Problem by adding following css rule to "Nav" container:

```
position: fixed;
```